# Is there a way to have the date always show up on the top bar in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If you hit <kbd>z</kbd> to goto stocks, you can see what the date is. I'd love to have the date always show up at the top. I've skimmed through the init file and don't see anything likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is not currently something that can be displayed. Though I do not know of any currently, I think it should be possible to display the date via a mod -- perhaps you should try asking on the Modding section of the bay12 forums?

Do note, that the date is also mentioned for any given <kbd>A</kbd>nnouncement, if you're trying to determine when something happened.

Comment: I wish there was a way to do it, but since apparently there isn't I'll go ahead and mark this one as the answer.

Comment: You can also press the `z` key to open the status screen. The current date will be printed in the top-right corner. This will be more accurate, as the announcements screen will only show the date of the most recent announcement (could be days old).